# Find the tuple with the right ID ruby

Tags: ruby

Hi I have a list of tuples (arrays) and I want to find the tuple that matches an ID in the first object of the tuple. As an example here's what the data looks like

```
[[object1, stat1],[object2, stat2], etc]
```

What I want to do is `detect` an object ID and then grab the stat to go with it. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do soemthing like this using ruby select: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select

```
a = [["object1", "stat1"],["object2", "stat2"]]
a.select { |elem| elem.include?("object1") }
```

Comment: I used string here.. you can replace string with object and achieve the same

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you convert your array

```
arr = [["object1", "stat1"],["object2", "stat2"],["object3", "stat3"]]
```

to a hash:

```
hash = Hash[arr]
  #=> {"object1"=>"stat1", "object2"=>"stat2", "object3"=>"stat3"}
```

or, for Ruby v2.0+

```
hash = arr.to_h
  #=> {"object1"=>"stat1", "object2"=>"stat2", "object3"=>"stat3"}
```

so that you can retrieve values directly:

```
hash["object2"] #=> "stat2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Find you say? Then how about using `Enumerable#find`?

```
a = [["object1", "stat1"],["object2", "stat2"],["object3", "stat3"]]
id = a[0][0].object_id
stat = a.find { |e| e[0].object_id == id }[1]
```